# angular-jsdoc - How to desribe $broadcast

Tags: angularjs, jsdoc, ngdoc

I have a service named 'utils'.
 This service have some methods.

Also, this service fire 2 broadcasts: "authUtilsFailed" and "authUtilsLoaded".

How can I document those 2 broadcasts ?
(Using angular-jsdoc)

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('utils', function ($http,$rootScope) {

        $http.get("api/Identity/").success(function (data) {
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data));
                self.uniqueId = data.id;
                self.displayName = data.displayName;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('authUtilsLoaded');
            }
            catch (err){
                $rootScope.$broadcast('authUtilsFailed');
            }
        }).error(function (error) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('authUtilsFailed');
        });
    });
```

Thanks,

kfir.

Comment: what u mean by document those 2 broadcasts ? ,

Comment: [`@fires`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-fires.html) tag?